# In ASP.NET MVC, what is the difference between <%= and <%:?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-4.0

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC. I've seen both **<%= ... %>** and **<%: ... %>**. I'm familiar with the first from classic ASP days, but not the latter. What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using <%: tells ASP.NET 4.0 to perform a Server.HtmlEncode() on the value being displayed.
Whereas using <%=, it is up to the developer to use Server.HtmlEncode().
Note HtmlEncode() helps void cross-scripting attacks.

For more info, see ScottGu's post [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx).

Answer (score 11):

`<%= %>` - equivalent to response.write in classic ASP.

`<% %>` - represents a code block, if, then else, for each, etc.

`<%: %>` - this is a shortcut new to .NET 4, this represents `<%= html.encode(item) %>`

[Link to video](http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc2-html-encoding) explaining the shortcut (it's a short clip):

Answer (score 1):

<%: expression %> is an HTML encoded expression and was introduced in ASP.NET 4

It is equivalent to <%= HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(expression) %>

Go [here](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4#0.2__Toc253429265) for more detail.